# Combining two collections and paginating them

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, pagination

So I have ads in a database.
There are 3 types for the ads. Featured, bold and free.
I want to display them in a page. First based on what category has been selected.
I want to show all featured first by added date and then after that all bold and free items by added date. And I want to paginate them.

I have tried this:

```
    $adsFeatured = Ads::where('category', '=', $category)->where('status', 'enabled')->where('type', 'featured')->get();
    $adsOther = Ads::where('category', '=', $category)->where('status', '=', 'enabled')->where('type', '=', 'free')->orWhere('type', '=', 'bold')->get();
    $adsOther->merge($adsFeatured);
    $adsFeatured->paginate(15);
```

But ofcourse it cannot be paginated if I use get(), but if i dont use it then i cant merge them, i want to merge them because i hope it would place them in that order.

Thanks for help, and I hope I have explained everything properly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that in one query. Try this

```
$ads = Ads::selectRaw('*, IF(type = "featured",1,0) AS is_featured')
          ->where('category', $category)
          ->where('status', 'enabled')
          ->orderBy('is_featured', 'desc')
          ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
          ->paginate(15);
```

Comment: It seems that it does get all the ads that should be in the category, but I cant get "$ad->id" or something like that.. How do i access the fields?

Comment: Ah sorry you have to select `*` plus the other field. See the edited answer